# Get content of file when downloaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Google Chrome extension to visualize some data stored in a csv files. I know this exists already with the [webrequest API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html).

The problem is that sometimes the file is generated by a php page and no webrequest is send.

I've looked at the [download API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html) that listens to downloads. I am now able to know when a download is done.

My question is:

**Can I access to the content of a file that has been downloaded, or that is being downloaded?**

.

---

Here is a code sample

```
chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(currentFile) {
    console.log(currentFile)
    // I would need to get the content of currentFile here.
});
```

Comment: I think that if you could, that would be a security risk/issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to get the contents of a downloaded file with a Chrome extension. It's not even possible to get access to such information through the `webRequest` API (it's a [popular feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058) though).

Usually, if you want the response body, you have to send a new request to the server (and hope that Chrome is getting the data from the cache). This method is unfortunately not very practical for non-GET (e.g. POST) request. There is no general way to solve this problem.

If you wish to get access to the response body, you have to develop a solution specific to your application, e.g. something that intercepts all POST requests for a particular page, and send the data back to the user (in order to save the file).

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'll try to figure out something specific to the website.